# Valid Reception of Baptized Christian into Full Communion (Roman Catholic)?

Tags: canon, canon-law

When a person who is validly baptized outside the Roman Catholic Church is received into Full Communion, must they recite the profession of faith themselves ("I believe and profess that...")? I was at an Easter Vigil 2 yrs ago, in which the priest simply turned it into a question, and the candidate merely had to answer "I do". My understanding of liturgical law is that this is an invalid Reception into Full Communion. Yes? No?

Comment: I don't know the rite for coming into Full Communion, but the profession of the faith in the form of questions is the normal way for the sacraments (baptism, First Communion, confirmation) - at least in Germany. So I see no problem.

Comment: Those questions are in fact based on a profession of faith and part of the ritual.